# VBA deleting duplicate values from 2 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list with 3 columns

[image: for example]

I want to delete any duplicate value with no shifting, the duplicated values can be both on the first column and on the second.

How can I do that?

I've tried something but it didn't work

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Columns("B:C").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
i = 1
x = 1
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    Cells(i, 4) = "=CONCATENATE(0,RC[-2])"
    i = i + 1
Loop
Do While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
    Cells(x, 5) = "=CONCATENATE(0,RC[-2])"
    x = x + 1
Loop
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Columns("D:E").ClearContents
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:C" & lRow)
End With

For x = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, rng(x)) > 1 Then
        rng(x).ClearContents
    End If
Next x

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing coming to mind is using a loop to go through each row of each column, match() the value in the activecell, and if it matches, delete and move to next cell in the range.

Comment: you can add the Macro to the Toolbar http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/add-a-macro-to-the-toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this where your two columns are B and C. It loops through all of the data and uses the worksheet function `COUNTIF` to check if there is more than one occurrence of each value and clears the contents of the cell if there is a count of more than 1:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim rng As Range
Dim x as Long
Dim lRow as Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B2:C" & lRow)
End With

For x = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, rng(x)) > 1 Then
        rng(x).ClearContents
    End If
Next x

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thnx. its works great. but i have a problem, ive made an actives bottun with the command ant it works, but when i trie to make the same code as a macro command it didnt work and the debuger highlighted the row "With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")". the name of the seet is "Sheet1" so i dont understand whats the prob

Comment: That's odd, are you sure there aren't any leading/trailing spaces in the name, e.g. " Sheet1" or "Sheet1 "? I'm not sure what else the issue could be - you could always just use `Thisworkbook.Sheets(1)` if the worksheet is the first one in the workbook.

Comment: ive uploaded the whole code, maybe the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @bakman you might be able to use the CodeName instead `With Sheet1` or maybe fully qualify it `Application.Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: nothing works, when i use the code in an activex button it does works, so is there a way to add this button to excel so it will apper wen ever i open an excel file?